# (R) aggregate error: invalid 'type' (list) of argument

Tags: r, aggregate

I am trying to sum TRUE values for two variables using a third columns but I am getting an error. Here is a code sample:

```
framea<-data.frame(v1=c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, NA, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE),
                   v2=c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, NA, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE),
                   v3=c("Blue", "Red","Blue", "Red","Blue", "Red","Blue", "Red","Blue", "Red","Blue", "Red","Blue"),
                  v4=c(1:4, 1:4, 1:5))
framea
attach(framea)
aggdata<-aggregate(formula=cbind(v1, v2)~v4, data=framea, by=list(v3), FUN=sum, na.rm = TRUE, na.action = NULL)
detach(framea)
aggdata
```

After the aggregate() step I get the following error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument
```

I ideally want something like the following output for aggdata:

```
          v1       v2
1 Blue     1        0
2 Blue     1        1
3 Blue     0        2
4 Blue     0        0
1 Red      2        2
2 Red      1        1 
3 Red      1        1
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You are using the formula method.  But, it doesn't have the `by` argument

Comment: Oh, I see. I will look more into that. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out thanks to the post from akrun above. I shouldn't have been using the formula= capability. Here is the answer:

```
framea<-data.frame(v1=c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, NA, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE),
                   v2=c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, NA, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE))
                   v3<-c("Blue", "Red","Blue", "Red","Blue", "Red","Blue", "Red","Blue", "Red","Blue", "Red","Blue")
                  v4<-c(1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:4)
framea
attach(framea)
aggdata<-aggregate(x=framea, by=list(v3, v4),FUN=sum, na.rm = TRUE, na.action = NULL)
detach(framea)
aggdata
```

(Let me know if I should delete this instead. Thanks.)

Comment: Keep it for reference. And instead of attaching and detaching, try `with(framea, aggregate(framea, by=list(v3,v4),..`

Comment: Or using the formula method `aggregate(cbind(v1,v2)~v3+v4, framea, FUN= sum, na.rm=TRUE, na.action=NULL)`  BTW the expected output you showed is different than the one you are getting from this.  I got confused by the output you showed

Comment: The output I actually get is ordered differently and labelled differently, but the essential numbers (sums) are the same. Does that make sense? Sorry for the confusion

Comment: I guess you are right.  Yes, the order confused me.  You don't have to delete the thread.  It may be useful to somebody in the future